# Replace a String at a specific index in a string?

Tags: java

How can we replace a particular string in existing string in Java?

Example:

```
String param = "aa,bb,cc";
String str = 
  "select column_val from table_name where a = '?' and b = '?' and c = '?'";
```

now i want replace params with its position like..

```
String newStr = 
  "select column_val from table_name where a = 'aa' and b = 'bb' and c = 'cc'";
```

How can we do this? Is there any existing method in stringutil or is there any method to do this?

Comment: Do you considered to use prepared statement instead of editing query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use StringBuilder. They offer some performance gain in your type of string manipulation, especially if your sql or params are long strings.

Here is an example:

```
String param = "aa,bb,cc";
String str = 
     "select column_val from table_name where a = '?' and b = '?' and c = '?'";

@Test
public void Substitute(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(str);

    String[] params = param.split(",");
    int position=0;
    for (String paramValue:params){
        position=builder.indexOf("?",position);
        if (position==-1)
            throw new RuntimeException("too parameter values specified.");
        builder.replace(position,position+1,paramValue);
        position++;
    }
    position=str.indexOf("?",position);
    if (position!=-1)
        throw new RuntimeException("Not all parameter specified.");

    Assert.assertEquals(builder.toString(),
          "select column_val from table_name where a = 'aa' and b = 'bb' and c = 'cc'");

}
```

As others have said, remember to sanitize param values to avoid security issues...

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to handle this is by [using](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). It will not only do the substitution for you, it will also guard you against [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

> yes i just demonstrate here select query but its not select query, it is simple string

In such a case, there is an easy way to do it:

```
 String param = "aa,bb,cc";
 String str = "select column_val from table_name where a = '?' and b = '?' and c = '?'";
 String fmt = str.replaceAll("[?]", "%s");
 String newStr = String.format(fmt, (Object[])param.split(","));
```

Make sure that the pattern you feed into this does not have any stray question marks or percent characters.

Comment: @sans481 - May be he just wanted to demonstrate a char/string replace ment in a string, in general. Sql string might be accidental here!

Comment: yes i just demonstrate here select query but its not select query, it is simple string , Ravinder is right thnks

Answer (score 0):

`String.format` sounds like what you should be using; it's basically like C's `sprintf`.  The details can be found in the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String param = "aa,bb,cc";
    String str = 
      "select column_val from table_name where a = # and b = # and c = #";
    String [] arr = param.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){str.indexOf("#");
        str = str.replaceFirst("#", "'"+arr[i]+"'");
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```